# I'm confused about accessing a file directory created by a sevlet

Tags: servlets, directory-structure

I have a GWT app that can correctly access servlet created files and directories in my development environment and also when deployed on my local Tomcat 7 installation but when I deploy it to my hosting company's server if fails to find the file directories that I create on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should include information about the path, since obviously that's important here.

Comment: Initially I was just using the following to obtain a web app relative path getServletContext().getRealPath("/index.html") and then using that to create the directories that I need after stripping off the "index.html" part.

Comment: You really need to provide more info about your folder structure and where the servlet is or I doubt anyone can help.

Comment: The servlet class file is contained in the WEB-INF\classes\com\webapp\server directory. It is mapped to the base of the web app such that it will respond to localhost:8080/WebApp/remote. During application startup it has the responsibility to create several directories at localhost:8080/WebApp/. I'm using ggts with the google gwt plugin which uses jetty and everything works as expected. When I deploy the WebApp.war to my local installation of tomcat 7 it works as expected. When I deploy to my host's server the directories are not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Running `getServletContext().getRealPath("/")` will return the app path (i.e. the part before /WEF-INF), like `C:\Tomcat7\webapps\WebApp\`.  So if your file is further down, somewhere under WEB-INF like `C:\Tomcat7\webapps\WebApp\classes\com\webapp\server\file.txt`, you're going to have to manually supply the rest of the path.

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "WEB-INF/classes/com/webapp/server/file.txt"
```

Edit: How to make sure you are calling this on the actual context:

```
private ServletContext context;
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
  this.context = config.getServletContext();
}
```

Then in your doPost or doGet:

```
context.getRealPath("/")
```

Comment: My hosting company's installation of tomcat 7 returns null for getServletContext().getRealPath("/") but will return an actual File object in response to getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR). But neither of them seem to expose an accessible directory.

Comment: See my edit on that. You need to store the context in your init method.